# sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 not displaying in rviz

Tags: rviz, pcl, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,

I am new to `ROS`. I have read binary files of laser dataset and prepared `sensor_msgs::PointCloud2` messages. But when i tried to view them in `rviz`, it not showing anything. Here is one of the  pointcloud message from `rostopic echo`. I would like to know what is the problem.

--thanks

```
header: 
  seq: 107
  stamp: 
    secs: 0
    nsecs: 0
  frame_id: laser_link
height: 1
width: 98322
fields: 
  - 
    name: x
    offset: 0
    datatype: 7
    count: 1
  - 
    name: y
    offset: 4
    datatype: 7
    count: 1
  - 
    name: z
    offset: 8
    datatype: 7
    count: 1
  - 
    name: r
    offset: 12
    datatype: 7
    count: 1
is_bigendian: False
point_step: 16
row_step: 1573152
Data : [201, 186, 100, .........<largedata> ..................]
is_dense: True
---
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/112371/sensor_msgs::pointcloud2-not-displaying-in-rviz/) by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3034 on 2013-12-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the pointcloud display in rviz under "Status", do you see that the one message arrived in rviz?

What is your 'Fixed Frame' (Global Options in rviz)? Set it to 'laser_link', or make sure there is a tf transform from the fixed frame to laser_link.

I'm not sure how exactly rviz handles timestamps, maybe the 0 timestamp of the message is an issue (but I guess it should still display).

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2013-12-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2013-12-22**:
@demmeln /map is my fixed frame and i am publishing /map to /odom tf and have static tf  for /base to /odom and /base to /laser. its not showing number of messages recieved.

**Comment by [VC](https://answers.ros.org/users/999/vc/) on 2013-12-22**:
@bvbdort the point cloud's frame is /laser_link according to the message, but your tf tree does not seem to have it ... name mismatch? Also, if your fixed frame is /map, the point cloud message time stamp will need to match with that of the tf broadcasters. Is the point cloud visible when you set the fixed frame to laser_link?

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2013-12-22**:
@VC yes i mean /laser is  /laser_link

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-01-06**:
@demmeln its not showing number of messages recieved

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-01-07**:
Hmmm... Can you check for errors with roswtf and then check if the publishing node and rviz are connected in rqt_graph?

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-01-07**:
@demmeln In rqt_graph its not showing anything related to rviz. No errors in roswtf.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-01-20**:
Sorry for the late reply. Have you set your fixed frame to laser_link? Are you publishing the message repeatedly, or just once? The number of messages received should show up if you open the "Status" entry in rviz. In rqt_graph untick "Hide Debug" to see rviz.

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-01-20**:
the problem is with data of pointcloud. When reading pointcloud data properly its working fine.